# fireEvent from Custom class

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have the following class ProtokollEvent

```
public class ProtokollEvent extends Event {

//variable holds all devices in given protokoll
private ObservableList<Device> devicesList;

//variable holds SaveResult
private SaveResult result;

//final ProtokollEvents
public static final EventType<ProtokollEvent> PROTOKOLL_SAVE = new EventType(ANY, "PROTOKOLL_SAVE");
public static final EventType<ProtokollEvent> PROTOKOLL_SAVE_DONE = new EventType(ANY, "PROTOKOLL_SAVE_DONE");
public static final EventType<ProtokollEvent> PROTOKOLL_UPDATED = new EventType(ANY, "PROTOKOLL_UPDATED");
public static final EventType<ProtokollEvent> PROTOKOLL_DELETED = new EventType(ANY, "PROTOKOLL_DELETED");

public ProtokollEvent() {
    this(PROTOKOLL_SAVE);
}

public ProtokollEvent(EventType<? extends Event> arg0) {
    super(arg0);
}

public ProtokollEvent(Object arg0, EventTarget arg1, EventType<? extends Event> arg2) {
    super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
}

/**
 * getDevices will return current {@link Device} as ObservableList
 *
 * @return {@link ObservableList} of type {@link Device}
 */
public ObservableList getDev() {
    return devicesList;
}
/**
 * setDevices will set devicesList
 * @param devices ObservableList {@link Device}
 */
public void setDev(ObservableList devices) {
    this.devicesList = devices;
}
/**
 * get the result which is returned from calling saveProtokoll
 * @return result {@link SaveResult}
 */
public SaveResult getResult() {
    return result;
}
/**
 * set the result which is returned after calling saveMessprotokoll in RestCall
 * @param result {@link SaveResult}
 */
public void setResult(SaveResult result) {
    this.result = result;
}
```

}

in the second class

```
public class SaveUtils {

private MainWindowController controller;
private ObservableList<RowContainerPruefvorschriftController> rows;
private Protokoll lastSavedProtokoll;
private Protokoll currentSavingProtokoll;

public SaveUtils(MainWindowController control){
    this.controller = control;
}

private void startSaving(){
    currentSavingProtokoll = createProtokoll();
    boolean state = controller.networkOnline.get() ? saveOnline() :saveOffline();
}

public void setRows(ObservableList<RowContainerPruefvorschriftController> rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
    //if rows get set start saveing the data
    startSaving();
}

private boolean saveOffline(){
    return false;
}
private boolean saveOnline() {
    RestCall call = controller.getCall();
    //call saveMessprotokoll and look what SaveResult returns
    SaveResult result = call.saveMessprotokoll(currentSavingProtokoll);
    //create ProtokollEvent to tell all consumers if all was ok
    ProtokollEvent save = new ProtokollEvent(ProtokollEvent.PROTOKOLL_SAVE_DONE);
    save.setResult(result);
    //HOW to fire/dispatch the ProtokollEvent here??????
    //TODO: need to fire this event and listen for it in other classes
    if(result.getResult()>0){
        controller.setLoggerMessage("SavedOnline->Protokoll-Nr.:"+result.getProtokollnr());
    }
    else {
        controller.setLoggerMessage("SavedOnline not successful->Error:"+result.getError_message());
    }        
    return true;
}
```

}

in the saveOnline function i create a ProtokollEvent and pass it some values.
What i now want is to fire or dispatch this event so other code parts could listen to this.

I tried with fireEvent() but as i understood the Oracle-DOCs only NODEs, Windows and Scene are able to do so. But how could i solve it with my custom class?

Additional i ask myself whats is the difference between fireEvent and dispatchEvent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution.
All events could be fired through the static method

```
Event.fireEvent(EventTarget eventTarget,Event event)
```

where eventTarget specifies the path through which the event will travel (taken from java docs).
So for my example i just added the following line

```
Event.fireEvent(controller.getMainWindowBorderPane(),save);
```

did it...