# Javafx: Close alert box (or, any dialog box) programatically

Tags: javafx, dialog

I have a JavaFx application in which I display an alert box using:

```
alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
alert.setTitle("Title");
alert.setHeaderText("Some Text");
alert.setContentText("Choose your option.");
buttonTypeOne = new ButtonType("Yes");
buttonTypeCancel = new ButtonType("No", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(buttonTypeOne, buttonTypeCancel);
Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
```

Because the alert executes`showAndWait`, so it will be displayed till the user either presses 'Yes' or 'No' or 'Close' the dialog.

Problem: I need to close this dialog programatically from somewhere else. To elaborate, if, let's say the user does not chose any option for 20 sec, or let's say this alert box was shown for some background process which just got over, and now I wish to close this alert box by setting `result` to be `buttonTypeCancel`, instead of the user pressing any button.
(Like `dispose` method in Swing)

How can I do this? I tried Event.fireevent (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22459308/3155986) but I am not able to write the correct event associated.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Including sample code-

1. MainApp.java - Java class responsible for handling the application
2. Controller.java - Corresponding controller file
3. Design.fxml - FXML file for the application which is loaded via MainApp.java and controlled by Controller.java
4. Compute.java - Another java class to perform computations.

   public class Compute{
       Alert alert;

   ```
   public void function1{
     Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
         public void run(){
         alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
         alert.setTitle("Title");
         alert.setHeaderText("Some Text");
         alert.setContentText("Choose your option.");
         buttonTypeOne = new ButtonType("Yes");
         buttonTypeCancel = new ButtonType("No", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
         alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(buttonTypeOne, buttonTypeCancel);

         Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
         if (result.get() == buttonTypeOne){
         // ... user chose "One"
         } else {
         // ... user chose CANCEL or closed the dialog
         }

         }
     });
   }

   public void function2{
    //......Does some long computation here 
    //.... If the computation finishes before the user chooses 'Yes' or 'No' on alert box
   //...Then close the alertbox here and execute the code corresponding to buttonTypeCancel


   //..I tried alert.close(); and alert.hide(); but doesn't work.
   }
   ```

   }

Also, is there any alternate solution to do this? Originally, I wanted to keep the `Compute.java` clean of any javafx code but couldn't figure out how.

Comment: If you have reference to `Window` (`Stage`) or `Alert` (`Dialog`), you can invoke .close() of both of them.

Comment: I tried .close()/ .hide() for the alertbox, but it doesn't execute. I wish to perform the code for `buttonTypeCancel` when the alertbox is closed forecefully from somewhere else from javacode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public void function2 {
    Button cancelButton = ( Button ) alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton( buttonTypeCancel );
    cancelButton.fire();
}
```

Or for more general

```
public void function2 {
    for ( ButtonType bt : alert.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes() )
    {
        if ( bt.getButtonData() == ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE )
        {
            Button cancelButton = ( Button ) alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton( bt );
            cancelButton.fire();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Full example:

```
@Override
public void start( final Stage primaryStage )
{
    Alert alert = new Alert( Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION );
    alert.setTitle( "Title" );
    alert.setHeaderText( "Some Text" );
    alert.setContentText( "Choose your option." );
    ButtonType buttonTypeOne = new ButtonType( "Yes" );
    alert.initModality( Modality.NONE );
    ButtonType buttonTypeCancel = new ButtonType( "No", ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE );
    alert.getButtonTypes().setAll( buttonTypeOne, buttonTypeCancel );

    Button b = new Button( "close alert" );
    b.setOnAction(( ActionEvent event ) ->
    {
        for ( ButtonType bt : alert.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes() )
        {
            System.out.println( "bt = " + bt );
            if ( bt.getButtonData() == ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE )
            {
                Button cancelButton = ( Button ) alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton( bt );
                cancelButton.fire();
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    final Scene scene = new Scene( new Group( b ), 400, 300 );
    primaryStage.setScene( scene );
    primaryStage.show();

    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
    if ( result.get() == buttonTypeOne )
    {
        System.out.println( "one " );
    }
    else if( result.get() == buttonTypeCancel )
    {
        System.out.println( "cancel " );
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Neither the alertbox closes, nor the code associated with `buttonTypeCancel` is executed.

Comment: This doesn't work either. And in the code, it should be `if ( bt.getButtonData() == ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE )`.

Comment: @DilpreetKaur. ButtonData is a enum defined in ButtonBar, so it is matter of how you import the classes. The ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE should work since it is a full package path.

Comment: The `for loop` and `if condition` works correctly (without ButtonBar), but the `cancelButton.fire()` event doesn't happen.

Comment: @DilpreetKaur, is cancelButton null? How do you know that the event doesn't fire?

Comment: Because the alertbox doesn't close, and the associated code for `buttonTypeCancel` is not executed.

Comment: @DilpreetKaur can you put the System.out.println( "bt = " + bt ); into for-loop and post the output.

Comment: `bt = ButtonType [text=Yes, buttonData=OTHER]
bt = ButtonType [text=No, buttonData=CANCEL_CLOSE]`

The execution goes into the forloop and if condition as well, but the alertbox doesn't close.

Comment: @DilpreetKaur, I posted a full example. Can you try it, and compare with yours. Run the app and click "close alert" button.

Comment: Your sample code works. Is there a problem with `Platform.runLater()`? Something to do with authorization over threads? Otherwise, the code looks fine and it should be working, but it isn't.

Comment: @DilpreetKaur honestly I don't know without debugging the code. Try wrapping the content of function2 into Platform.runLater().

Comment: Fixed it. Just like I'm invoking the alertbox in `Platform.runLater()`, similarly, I had to invoke the alert.close() in `Platform.runLater()`.
In all, to invoke anything related to GUI outside of MainApp.java, use `Platform.runLater().`

Comment: @DilpreetKaur, glad to hear that. I think it answers to your main question so you may accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke [`close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#close--) method on the Alert or any Dialog.

Here is a simple example which waits for 5 secs, and if the Alert is still showing, it closes it.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Optional;

public class Main extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Title");
        alert.setHeaderText("Some Text");
        alert.setContentText("Choose your option.");
        ButtonType buttonTypeOne = new ButtonType("Yes");
        ButtonType buttonTypeCancel = new ButtonType("No", ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
        alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(buttonTypeOne, buttonTypeCancel);

        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                // Wait for 5 secs
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                if (alert.isShowing()) {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> alert.close());
                }
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nicer if you use a proper timer, apparently JavaFX has Timeline for that.

Comment: Of course you can, [`PauseTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html) being a better option IMHO. This solution was a generic approach, you can always replace the thread with whatever you like :)

Comment: Thanks, PauseTransition is good. I noticed that alert.close() only works if you have a button type with ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE or you manually call alert.setResult first. Also, there are predefined buttons for "Yes", "No", etc (ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO...) but if I use those, it puts them in a weird order and highlights one of them (the YES button). Looks like ButtonBar does that based on the ButtonData values.

Answer (score 0):

It's closing opened **dialog** in 2 second.

```
dialog = new Dialog<>();
dialog.setTitle("It's a dialog!");
dialog.show();

    Thread newThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dialog.close();
                }
                });
            }
    });
    newThread.start();
```