# Close an existing alert without button in runLater

Tags: javafx, dialog, javafx-8, observable

I want my application to open a dialog that the user can not close, but that it closes when his phone is reconnected (he is patient with the open dialog)

I'm currently openning the alert dialog with Platform.runlater like this :

```
phoneConnected.getObservable().addListener(observable -> {
      LOG.info("identifyObs " + phoneConnected.getBooleanDataValue().getValue());
      if (phoneConnected.getBooleanDataValue() != null && !phoneConnected.getBooleanDataValue().getValue()) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> alert.show());
      }
      if (phoneConnected.getBooleanDataValue().getValue()) {
        System.out.println("ok");
        alert.close();
        Platform.runLater(() -> alert.close());
      }
    });
```

The fact is, when the observable is going to "true", I've got the "ok" in the console, but the dialog don't close ..

I've tried in runLater , out the runLater, any ideas ?

I would to say, I've seen this : [Javafx: Close alert box (or, any dialog box) programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755370/javafx-close-alert-box-or-any-dialog-box-programatically#comment49646779_30772540) but it's not working ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `Alert` does not close properly if the result is not set and no buttons are available. You can work around this by assigning an arbitrary `ButtonType` as result:

```
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.NONE, "wait for it");

// set result to allow programmatic closing of alert
alert.setResult(ButtonType.OK);

Button btn = new Button("Start");
btn.setOnAction(evt -> {
    btn.setDisable(true);

    // make alert appear / disappear
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        boolean showing = false;
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NewFXMain2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            Runnable action = showing ? alert::close : alert::show;
            Platform.runLater(action);
            showing = !showing;
        }
    });
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
});
```

Comment: Yes ! That's it, i just needed the "alert.setResult(ButtonType.OK);" in my code, it's now working like a charm !

Comment: hmm ... sounds like a bug (?) - or could we imagine any use-case where such a behaviour is wanted/needed?

Comment: okay, think I understand the logic: a) programmatic close is in the same "abnormal" category as closing by window button b) api doc of dialog.close specifies rules when abnormal closing is allowed to actually close. Which is i) having exactly one button or ii) having multple buttons one of which is cancel_close. AlertType.NONE doesn't have buttons, so it hits the (unspecified? seen in the implementation of fxDialog.permissionToClose) special case that the result must be != null. You found a perfect hack for a corner case :)